# Rails 4.0.5 - Handling params with arrays containing empty strings

Tags: arrays, forms, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-chosen

Since I switched to Rails 4.0.5, some undesired behavior began occurring with a form for a model that uses a postgresql string array.

```
  def up
    add_column :cuts, :states, :text, :array => true
  end
```

The form uses a `collection_select`

```
    <%=
      f.collection_select(
        :states,
        states,
        :last,
        :first,
        {},
        :multiple => true,
        :class => 'chosen chosen_allow_deselect'
      )
    %>
```

I've tried forcing an `:include_blank => false` as well, but regardless, if I submit the form without selecting any states, `params[:cut][:states]` evaluates to `[""]`, which winds up being written to the database. Now my `states` field is not blank when it should be.

Obviously I could write a `before_validation` callback or an `attribute_normalizer` to clean the array, but I'm hoping that there's some way I can just turn this "feature" off and prevent Rails from interpreting the form input this way.

Note that multi-selects for HABTM relationships also send over an array with a blank string, but Rails knows how to handle it and doesn't try to assign a record for the blank value. This only seems to create a real problem when the field is an actual array.

**Update**

To be specific, what I'm hoping is that there's a form helper option that I'm unaware of that well prevent blanks from being submitted when nothing's selected and there's no blank `<option>` tag. Our servers are currently using 4.0.2, and this problem does not occur on the servers at all. The application code that I'm executing locally is identical to what's running on the servers. This is how I conclude that the new version of Rails is doing something different.

**Update**

After reviewing the html again, I think it's chosen doing it with one of the hidden inputs it creates; it adds an input like this:

`<input name="cut[states][]" type="hidden" value="">`

This leads me to believe that it's been doing this all along and that the change in behavior is in ActiveRecord rather than a form submission issue.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "without selecting any states", do you mean that you selected the blank option in the select?  If so then there could be times where that is a valid option, and if you did some across-the-board "turn all empty strings into nil" solution, that could well end up biting you in the ass somewhere else.

If you don't want to ever save an empty string to your 'states' field (saving nil instead) then you could override the setter method.

```
#in Cut model
def states=(string)
  if string.blank?
    self[:states] = nil
  else 
    self[:states] = string
  end
end
```

Comment: There isn't a blank ```<option>``` tag to select, and I've selected nothing. Also, my field is an array of strings, not a string. And I'm aware that I can clean it in the model. I'm looking for some kind of option in the form helper that prevents it from submitting blanks if nothing's selected. Previously it did not submit blanks.

Comment: What is the select set to when the page loads?

Comment: It is not set to anything. Inspecting the ```<select>``` element with JavaScript reveals a null value.

Comment: Can you post the rendered html of the select?

Comment: After reviewing the html again, I think it's chosen doing it with one of the hidden inputs it creates, leading me to believe that it's been doing this all along and that the change in behavior is in ActiveRecord rather than a form submission issue :(

Answer (score 0):

A simple and straight forward way to solve this that embraces the Rails conventions would be to write your own setter method like the following

```rb
# app/models/cut.rb

def states=(values)
  self[:states] = values.compact_blank
end
```

[`compact_blank`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-compact_blank) will remove any blank strings from the input so `["", "NC", "NY"]` becomes `["NC", "NY"]`.

More importantly, `[""]` becomes `[]` and can unset the array when you ***don't*** add `{include_blank: false}` to the `select` field. The [gotcha](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select-label-Gotcha) in the Rails API docs explains why this is. The `tl;dr` is that selecting nothing will not send the param to the server making the behavior ambiguous. As the OP pointed out, this is how Rails handles unsetting HABTM relationships.